# Android: 2 problems with a custom TabWidget

Tags: android, tabs, android-tabhost, tabwidget

I'm trying to create custom tabs *beneath* the action bar. My action bar is already taken up by other widgets, so moving the tabs to the action bar is not an option. The tabs need to have both images and text. I'm having 2 problems:

1) When I do this:

```
mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("Local").setIndicator("Local", getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.local_selector)).setContent(R.id.local_image));
```

I see the text and no image. If I do this:

```
mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("Local").setIndicator("", getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.local_selector)).setContent(R.id.local_image));
```

I see the image, but I haven't included the desired text.

2) The background color of the text and image do not match the color of the TabWidget. It matches the default background color of the entire app.

I've also tried creating the tabs in a RelativeLayout and implementing them like this:

```
RelativeLayout localView = (RelativeLayout)inflater.inflate(R.layout.local_tab, null);
mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("Local").setIndicator(localView).setContent(R.id.local_image));
```

This gives me the desired image+text combo with the correct background color, but the tabs no longer look like tabs. There are no dividers and the selected tab doesn't light up.

Comment: use `selector` (read about it )  as background for your tabwidget

Comment: Actually, I've tried that, too, with no difference.

Maybe if you gave me an example of the proper way to use it?

Comment: for the background layout of your TabWidget, create drawable xml for each tabwidget like this : `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<item android:drawable="@drawable/tab_1_pressed" android:state_pressed="true"/>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/tab_1_selected" android:state_selected="true"/>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/tab_1_normal"/>

</selector>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution to my problem. In my theme, I was setting android:background instead of android:windowBackground. Once I used android:windowBackground, the colors worked together better.

Then I created new image with the text included. After lots of tweaking, I eventually got it to look the way I wanted.

Answer (score 1):

try this may be it help you.

```
tabHost = getTabHost();
    TabSpec spec_info = tabHost.newTabSpec(getString(R.string.info));
    spec_info.setIndicator(getString(R.string.info), null);
    Intent Intent_info = new Intent(this, RestaurantInfoActivity.class);
    spec_info.setContent(Intent_info);
    tabHost.addTab(spec_info);
    tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildTabViewAt(0).setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.tab_selector));
```

xml

```
<TabHost
                xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:orientation="vertical" 
                    android:fadingEdge="none"
                    android:overScrollMode="never"
                    >

                    <TabWidget
                        android:id="@android:id/tabs"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                        android:tabStripEnabled="false" />

                    <FrameLayout
                        android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
                </LinearLayout>
            </TabHost>
```

selector

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<!-- When selected, use white-->
<item android:drawable="@drawable/active_tab"
      android:state_selected="true" />
<!-- When not selected, use grey -->
<item android:drawable="@drawable/in_active_tab" >
</item>
```

Comment: Thanks, but Houvin, your solution is the same as what I tried before with no difference, and Bhavin, your solution gives me my image stretched out and ugly, and the text is on top of it, not below it, and the text still has the wrong background color.

Comment: try to download and implement this is the best example. may be it helps you.http://www.androidhive.info/2012/05/android-combining-tab-layout-and-list-view/